# Number Theory: Divisible by 3 Proof

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I am attempting to proof the following:

for any positive integer $a$, either $3|a$ or $3|(a^2 - 1)$

I started by considering the different cases for the remainder of $a/3$, which are obviously 0, 1, and 2.

The first case is simple, since if the remainder is 0, then $3|a$.

For the remaining cases, $3|a$ is obviously false, but I am having trouble proving that $3|(a^2 - 1)$ is true.

Any hints to point me in the correct direction are greatly appreciated; I would like to proceed in this direction if possible.

Comment: write $a=3b+1$ or $3b+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest proof is to appeal to laws of modulus calculation ($a\equiv 1 \mod 3$ implies $a^2-1\equiv 1^2-1=0,$ etc.), but a direct proof is as follows:

If $a=3k+1,$ then $a^2-1=3(3k^2+2k),$ a multiple of $3.$

If $a=3k+2,$ then $a^2-1=3(3k^2+4k+1),$ also a multiple of $3.$

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ has a remainder of $1$ upon division by $3$ (i.e., $a \equiv 1 \pmod 3$) then what can you say about the reminder when $a^2$ is divided by $3$? And $a^2-1$? (Hint: you can write $a=3k+1$ for some integer $k$. Then compute $a^2-1$.)

You can do a similar thing in the case $a \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1.** $a-1, a, a+1$ are $3$ consecutive numbers (e.g. $\binom{a+1}{3}$ is integer), thus $3 \mid (a-1)a(a+1)$ or $3 \mid a (a^2-1)$. But $3$ is also a prime number and from [Euclid lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), either $3 \mid a$ or $3 \mid (a^2-1)$.

**Version 2.** From [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $3 \mid a^3-a$ and from [Euclid lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), either $3 \mid a$ or $3 \mid (a^2-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any positive integer $a$, the set $\{(a-1), a, (a+1)\}$ is 3 consecutive integers, thus one of them is divisible by 3.  Since $a^2-1 = (a-1)(a+1)$, it leads to either $3|a$ or $3|(a^2−1)$.

Comment: 2 minutes late ;)